# Issue with parsing array of dictionaries

Tags: json, swift

I'm having a json response like so...

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "TotalRevenue": “123.12 K",
    "Productdata": [
        {
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": “abc”
            "product_images": [
                {
                    "id": "938",
                    "image": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_15",
                    "is_default": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "939",
                    "image": "http://myApp.direct.com/public165_1_image_16",
                    "is_default": "0"
                }

            ]
        }
```

I began by parsing like so...

```
if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
    if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
        if result["success"] as! Int == 0 {
            //Do something
        }  else if result["success"] as! Int == 1 {
            let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [String:Any]
            print(prodArray!)   //CRASHED HERE

            let prodId = prodArray?["product_id"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
            print(prodId)
        }
    }
}
```

But at `prodArray`, it crashed saying it unexpectedly found nil.. Can anyone help with regard to how a proper parsing can be done in this case..?

Comment: besides the fact that you shouldn't force cast your dictionary value, success it is probably a Bool that when it is stored as NSNumber becomes 0 or 1 so you should conditionally cast it as? Bool. `if result["success"] as? Bool == true {` and than just a regular `} else {`

Comment: You should use swiftyjson! It makes doing this a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your `JSON` it is very clear that **Productdata** is array of Dictionary not `[String:Any]`

replace your code with

```
guard let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
```

And one more thing **product_id** is Only String   **NOT** `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`

So,

```
let prodId = prodArray?["product_id"] as? String
```

**You can combine both also Here is Full Code**

---

```
guard  let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] ,result["success"] as! Int == 0 else { return }

guard let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]],let prodId = prodArray.first?["product_id"] as? String  else { return }
```

---

### Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: @JonSnow no need to check if it is not empty for force unwrap it later. Just use optional chaining `let prodId = prodArray.first?["product_id"] as? String`

Comment: is there a blog which tells that what is the mechanism of parsing. and where do swiftyjson and dictionary and success being bool stand in that.

Comment: @rd_ Read this http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/12/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-3/ , all you need is practice

Comment: @JonSnow sorry for bothering again...but just a concern...things were working fine till yesterday..:) but when the same parsing was tried again, the productArray is showing empty inspite of data being shown in Postman. This certainly wasn't the case before...:(

Comment: @User.bw Are you getting response.result.value ?

Comment: response.result.value shows the productData as empty..!

Comment: @JonSnow..please don't bother yourself...it was an error on my part...I was logging in with an user that didn't have any details associated with him...

Comment: @User.bw  What you need is debugging , If you will debug you can find problem very easily and also get idea to solve it  :)

Answer (score 0):

First:
Don't use force unwrapping. It was introduced into Swift to facilitate bridging from Objective-C, using it otherwise is a bad practice.

Second:
The reason for your crash is this

```
let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [String:Any]
```

`[String:Any]` is a Dictionary, while you need an Array of Dictionaries

```
let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]]
```

Full snippet:

```
guard let prodArray = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] else { break }
print(prodArray)

guard prodArray.count > 0 else { break }
let firstDict = prodArray[0]
guard let prodId = firstDict["product_id"] as? NSNumber else { break }
print(prodId)
```

Comment: better/safer to use `.first` instead of `[0]`

Comment: That's why I check if the array is not empty, but you're right - `.first` looks cleaner

Comment: btw Don't use `.count > 0`. Collection has a property `isEmpty` exactly for that